# Intermittent Nulls Returned From TaxonomySession DefaultKeywordsTermStore

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, sharepoint-server

I have created a SharePoint 2010 (SP1) timer job which utilises the SharePoint Managed Metadata Service.

The code I have is :

```
// Get the taxonomy session
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(this.SharePointSite);
if (session == null)
{
   LoggingService.LogVerbose("Taxonomy store unavailable");
   return null;
}
// Get the default keyword TermStore for the provided site
TermStore defaultKeywordStore = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;
if (defaultKeywordStore == null)
{
    LoggingService.LogVerbose("Default Keyword store unavailable for Taxonomy Session");
    return null;
}
```

From time to time, `defaultKeywordStore` is returned as null - occasionally, for periods, every `defaultKeywordStore` is returned as null for every call.

Anyone seen this sort of behaviour before?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. Any one has any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, please make sure all the below settings are properly intact, if not then you get the above error time to time.

1. First of all check that your web application has connection with
   managed metadata service in Central administration > Manage web
   applications > Service connection and make sure only **one MMS
   associated with the web app,** DefaultKeywordsTermStore returned null
   when there were several managed metadata connections defined for
   single web application
2. Manage service applications > select Managed metadata service
   connection and click Properties button on the ribbon. On the opened
   dialog ensure that option “**This service application is the default
   storage location for Keywords**” and “**This service application is the
   default storage location for column specific term sets**".
3. Go to Manage service applications > select Managed metadata service
   application and click Permissions button on the ribbon.Ensure that
   account under which you run the code has at least “**Read access to
   term store**” right.

Check here for more details.
http://venkychilukuri.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/taxonomysession-defaultkeywordstermstore-and-defaultsitecollectiontermstore-can-be-null/

Comment: I have checked the above steps, but it still becomes null intermittently. Has anyone got any solution for this yet?